# Indian national travelling from Kuwait to Dubai by road

Tags: indian-citizens, road-trips, dubai, kuwait

I am an Indian national, and I'm currently staying in Kuwait with legal residency. I want to travel to Dubai by car with my family.

Can you please guide us on the complete procedure with any requirements we might have to meet?

Comment: This is quite a broad question, you might need to narrow it down (you can edit your post to add additional information). What in particular do you need help with? Is it the route? (if so, let us know what in particular you're concerned about after looking the route up on Google Maps) Or, is it the visa requirements? If you can provide as much information as possible we might be able to help.

Comment: My (educated) guess is that the drive goes through Saudi Arabia which does not issue tourist visas. It used to issue transit visas then suspended them but perhaps only for US citizens. Call the Saudi embassy whether it's possible for you and your family to pass through.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify/edit. Putting on hold.

Answer (score 3):

*My latest understanding is that transit visas are currently blocked in Saudi Arabia for non-nationals, but you can try your luck at the Saudi Embassy visa office, they may have the latest updates.*

You will need to obtain a transit visa for Saudi Arabia, for all passengers on the trip. To obtain the transit visa, you'll need to obtain first a UAE visa (it is a requirement).

The transit visa is valid for 3 days.

To obtain the visa, you'll need:

1. Passport and residency that is more than 6 months current.
2. Photos with white background for each passenger.
3. Proof of UAE visa.
4. Cash for visa (I believe it is 23 KD each passport).

In addition, I recommend getting a [triptych](http://www.fia.com/travel-documents). I travel often across the border and *technically* you don't need it as you are not leaving the GCC but it is better to obtain it anyway - you might get asked especially if it is the first time the car is traveling. You can get this from the auto club which is located on the intersection of the 4th ring road and Ghazali.

Gather those documents and go to the Waseet office which is located behind the North Nugra complex in Hawally ([google map link](https://www.google.com.kw/maps/place/ATM+North+Al-Nuqrah/@29.3319924,48.0087841,18.5z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x3fcf9c85c68700a7:0x92e39154c8b102f!2sSouthern+Nugra+Complex!3b1!8m2!3d29.3318968!4d48.00909!3m4!1s0x0000000000000000:0x11ee8f8e235ba960!8m2!3d29.332624!4d48.0088162?hl=en)).

They are open in the morning from 8 till 12, and then in the afternoon after 4 PM.

If you don't speak Arabic, it is best to grab a friend that does as the staff there have very elementary knowledge of English.

If you are granted the visa, you'll need to travel through the Nuwaiseeb border point. From there, it is pretty much a straight shot down to the UAE on Saudi Highway 95; the journey will take around 12/13 hours.

If this is your first time traveling by road through Saudi Arabia, please note the following:

1. Women are not allowed to drive.
2. If you have any female companions, they have to be dressed modestly (no shorts, bare shoulders).
3. You'll need to obtain vehicle insurance at the Saudi border. It is less than 100 SAR (less than 10 KD) for three days; you will have to obtain separate insurance for the UAE at the UAE border.
4. Gas stations take cash only, and gasoline is available in 91/95 RON only. There is no 98 RON as available in Kuwait (called "ultra super").
5. All businesses close during times of prayer.
6. There are camera speed traps on the highways.
7. Most gas stations have only minimal services, try to stop at the SASCO stations which are better fitted and well maintained.
8. You will very rarely find sitting toilets on the road side stations.
9. If you stick to the SASCO branded stops, you'll find restaurants that have family seating; otherwise your female companions will have to eat in the car.